# Problema com Spring Security - página não localizada

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, spring, spring-security

Quando o usuário acessa uma página que ele não tem autorização, é para ele ser direcionado para a página de `AcessoNegado.xhtml`. Porém apresenta a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa página está localizada aqui:

```
\GestaoADM\src\main\webapp\AcessoNegado.xhtml
```

[image: erro]

E a configuração está no `applicationContext.xml`;

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="appUserDetailsService"
        class="br.com.gestaoadm.security.AppUserDetailsService" />


    <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="jsfAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsfAccessDeniedHandler"
        class=" br.com.gestaoadm.security.JsfAccessDeniedHandler">
        <beans:property name="loginPath" value="/AcessoNegado.xhtml" />
        <beans:property name="contextRelative" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class=" br.com.gestaoadm.security.JsfLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/Login.xhtml" />
        <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy"
        class=" br.com.gestaoadm.security.JsfRedirectStrategy" />




    <http pattern="/Login.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/Erro.xhtml" security="none" />

    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">

        <custom-filter ref="exceptionTranslationFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />


        <intercept-url pattern="/Inicio.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/imovel/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('CORRETORES','ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/empresa/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cliente/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <form-login login-page="/Login.xhtml"

            authentication-failure-url="/Login.xhtml?invalid=true"
            default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" />

        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            invalidate-session="true" />


    </http>

    <!-- <authentication-manager> -->
    <!-- <authentication-provider> -->
    <!-- <user-service> -->
    <!-- <user name="joao" password="joao" authorities="CORRETORES" /> -->
    <!-- <user name="wladimir" password="wladimir" authorities="ADMINISTRADORES" 
        /> -->
    <!-- </user-service> -->
    <!-- </authentication-provider> -->
    <!-- </authentication-manager> -->

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="appUserDetailsService">
            <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5" /> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>



</beans:beans>
```

O trecho de importância está aqui:

```xml
<beans:bean id="jsfAccessDeniedHandler"
    class=" br.com.gestaoadm.security.JsfAccessDeniedHandler">
    <beans:property name="loginPath" value="/AcessoNegado.xhtml" />
    <beans:property name="contextRelative" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

O que será que está errado?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta, talvez possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489911/this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-in-spring-security-application

Comment: Aqui não abre a imagem pra mim. Talvez o meu proxy esteja bloqueando. Qual a mensagem que aparece na tela?

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece que você não definiu qual é a permissão necessária para acessar a página de acesso negado.

Então quando o usuário é redirecionado o spring vê q ele não tem permissão para a página de acesso negado e tenta redirecionar para ... a página de acesso negado, a qual ele não tem permissão e assim infinitamente.

pra resolver isso coloque esse interceptor:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/AcessoNegado.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```